# Mdash in transcript of records permitted

Tags: phd, thesis, masters, formatting, titles

When a degree is accomplished my University gives you a final official transcript of records and a final certificate for the degree, both containing the title of your thesis. For some reason the internal system of my University does neither allow ndashs nor mdashs on the final transcript of records of an accomplished degree, but it allows them on the final certificate. On the certificate my title will be something like:

> title beginning—title end

i.e. it contains an mdash. As the mdash can not be used on the transcript of records I have now been asked, if I would like to have it approximated like "---", "--", or "-" on the transcript of records. I dislike all options very much, but tend to go for the single hyphen. I know that wikipedia tells you to approximate it like "--", or "---", but is this really the 'most correct' way to deal with that on an official document?

Thanks in advance for your opinion!

Comment: This is highly subjective and, frankly, it doesn't matter in the least as far as your further career is concerned. If you are asking out of interest in typography, the stack exchange sites for graphic design or -- perhaps -- LaTeX might be more pertinent. But check on their meta sites first.

Comment: Your problem does not have any particular relation to academia. Everybody working with legacy encodings may be forced to make such decisions. If you decide to ask on [graphicdesign.se], please state some criteria according to which you would evaluate your makeshift solution (approximating looks, least confusion, etc.) otherwise it could be too opinion-based. — @henning: *perhaps […] LaTeX might be more pertinent* – I know you said *perhaps,* but what does LaTeX have to do with makeshift solutions for some unrelated legacy software?

Comment: @Wrzlprmft The LaTeX folks may know what the "most correct" approximation is, but I agree that it's off-topic. Don't ask them.

Comment: Is your degree in typography?

Answer (score 2):

There is no "most correct" way because it is of no consequence whatsoever. Write one dash, write two, write three: it does not matter. Nobody will do more than glance at the piece of paper on which it is written, and if by miracle they notice that the dash is shorter than on your thesis they will barely give it any thought. The police will not arrest you because you put two dashes instead of three. In a week you will have forgotten the issue completely and it will never come up again. You are overthinking this.